# python-vlc + wxpython freezes on Raspberry pi 4b

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wxpython, libvlc, python-vlc

I have Raspberry pi 4b and I am trying to run python-vlc and wxpython to play video.

```
import vlc
import time
import threading
import wx



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Video Frame WxPython", size=wx.GetDisplaySize())

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, id= -1, pos=(0,0), size=wx.GetDisplaySize(), style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)   # EDIT#1

        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.Show()


def foo():
    global frame   # EDIT#1
    vlc_options = '--no-xlib --verbose 2'  # EDIT#1
    inst = vlc.Instance(vlc_options)
    player = inst.media_player_new()

    m1 = inst.media_new('lang_CZ.mp4')
    time.sleep(0.1)   # EDIT#1
    player.set_xwindow(frame.panel.GetHandle())  # EDIT#1
    while True:
        print("-------")  # EDIT#1
        player.set_media(m1)
        player.play()
        time.sleep(10)
        player.stop()



app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()

thr = threading.Thread(target=foo)
thr.start()


app.MainLoop()


print(thr.is_alive())
thr.join()
```

The problem is that after few while loop iterations gprahical window freezes and it's not working until reboot of raspberry pi. Vlc is not showing any errors and also if I run `cvlc` after this it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I added `--verbose 2` into `vlc_options`, `player.set_xwindow(frame.panel.GetHandle())` before `while True` and `self.ShowFullScreen(True)` into `MyFrame` class. Here is the output from the last successfull play (after `print("-------")`):

```
-------
[b1576280] main input debug: Creating an input for 'lang_CZ.mp4'
[b1576280] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[b1576280] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[b1576280] main input debug: `file:///home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4' gives access `file' demux `any' path `/home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4'
[9fd089d8] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4' file='/home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4'
[9fd07a48] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 17 candidates
[9fd07a48] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[9fd0b138] main stream debug: creating access: file:///home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4
[9fd0b138] main stream debug:  (path: /home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4)
[9fd0b138] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 28 candidates
[9fd0b138] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[9fd0a9f0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[9fd0a9f0] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[9fd0a9f0] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[9fd0a9f0] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[9fd0a9f0] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 3472 KiB/s
[9fd0a9f0] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[9fd023e8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/pi/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/anevia_streams.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/anevia_xml.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/appletrailers.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/bbc_co_uk.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/cue.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/dailymotion.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/jamendo.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/koreus.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/liveleak.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/newgrounds.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/rockbox_fm_presets.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/soundcloud.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/twitch.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/vimeo.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/vocaroo.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.luac
[9fd023e8] lua stream debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/playlist
[9fd023e8] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[9fd0ac20] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[9fd0ac20] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[9fd089d8] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4
[9fd023e8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[9fd023e8] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[9fd089d8] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4' file='/home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4'
[9fd06868] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "mp4": 55 candidates
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream warning: unknown box type stik (incompletely loaded)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream warning: unknown box type tvsn (incompletely loaded)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream warning: unknown box type tves (incompletely loaded)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream warning: unknown box type hdvd (incompletely loaded)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: dumping root Box "root"
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   + ftyp size 20 offset 0
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   + moov size 310863 offset 20
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + mvhd size 108 offset 28
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + trak size 100838 offset 136
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 144
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + mdia size 100738 offset 236
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 244
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 45 offset 276
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + minf size 100653 offset 321
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + vmhd size 20 offset 329
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 349
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 357
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 373
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 100589 offset 385
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 149 offset 393
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avc1 size 133 offset 409
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avcC size 47 offset 495
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 24 offset 542
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stss size 2072 offset 566
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 28 offset 2638
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 49156 offset 2666
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 49152 offset 51822
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + trak size 208954 offset 100974
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 100982
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + mdia size 208832 offset 101074
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 101082
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 45 offset 101114
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + minf size 208747 offset 101159
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + smhd size 16 offset 101167
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 101183
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 101191
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 101207
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 208687 offset 101219
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 91 offset 101227
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + mp4a size 75 offset 101243
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + esds size 39 offset 101279
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 24 offset 101318
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 77776 offset 101342
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 84692 offset 179118
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 46096 offset 263810
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + udta size 22 offset 309906
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + name size 14 offset 309914
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + udta size 955 offset 309928
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + meta size 947 offset 309936
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 34 offset 309948
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + ilst size 901 offset 309982
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + stik size 25 offset 309990 (????)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + tvsn size 28 offset 310015 (????)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + tves size 28 offset 310043 (????)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + hdvd size 25 offset 310071 (????)
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + ---- size 715 offset 310096
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + mean size 28 offset 310104
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + name size 20 offset 310132
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + data size 659 offset 310152
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + ---- size 72 offset 310811
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + mean size 28 offset 310819
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + name size 20 offset 310847
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + data size 16 offset 310867
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   + free size 8 offset 310883
[9fd023e8] mp4 stream debug: |   + mdat size 158370850 offset 310891
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: unrecognized major media specification (mp42).
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: found 2 tracks
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] read 12284 chunk
[9fd06868] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] read 12284 samples length:491s
[b1576280] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: adding track[Id 0x1] video (enable) language eng
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x2] read 11520 chunk
[9fd06868] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x2] read 21168 samples length:491s
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: adding track[Id 0x2] audio (enable) language eng
[9fd06868] main demux debug: using demux module "mp4"
[b1576280] main input debug: looking for a subtitle file in /home/pi/
[9fd2e400] main decoder debug: looking for video decoder module matching "any": 18 candidates
[9fd2e400] mmal_codec decoder debug: OpenDecoder: <<< (h264/----)[H264] 768x576 0/0=0/0 o:0 -> (----/----) 0x0 0/0 o:0
[9fd2e400] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
[9fd2e400] main decoder debug: using video decoder module "mmal_codec"
[9fd3b328] main decoder debug: looking for audio decoder module matching "any": 21 candidates
[9fd3b328] main decoder debug: using audio decoder module "faad"
[9fd0b5d8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[9fd0b5d8] main demux meta debug: using meta reader module "taglib"
[9fd06868] main demux debug: removing module "taglib"
[b1576280] main input debug: `file:///home/pi/lang_CZ.mp4' successfully opened
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] using Sync Sample Box (stss)
[9fd06868] mp4 demux debug: stss gives 0 --> 0 (sample number)
[b1576280] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[9fd3b328] faad decoder warning: decoded zero sample
[b15628f0] main generic debug: creating audio output
[9f32e940] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[9f32e940] vlcpulse audio output debug: using library version 12.2.0
[9f32e940] vlcpulse audio output debug:  (compiled with version 12.2.0, protocol 32)
[b1576280] main input debug: Buffering 25%
[b1576280] main input debug: Buffering 50%
[b1576280] main input debug: Buffering 75%
[b1576280] main input debug: Buffering 100%
[b1576280] main input debug: Stream buffering done (1250 ms in 11 ms)
[b0b4c180] main spu text debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
[b0b4c180] freetype spu text debug: Building font databases.
[b0b4c180] freetype spu text debug: Took -32427 microseconds
[b0b4c180] main spu text debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
[b0b12d00] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
[b0b12d00] swscale scale debug: 32x32 (32x32) chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 (16x16) chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
[b0b12d00] main scale debug: using video converter module "swscale"
[b0b20480] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
[b0b20480] yuvp scale debug: YUVP to YUVA converter
[b0b20480] main scale debug: using video converter module "yuvp"
[b0b2ab78] main video output debug: Deinterlacing available
[b0b2ab78] main video output debug: deinterlace -1, mode auto, is_needed 0
[b0b15b08] main window debug: looking for vout window module matching "embed-xid,any": 6 candidates
[b155d168] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 0: alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.digital-stereo (Built-in Audio Digital Stereo)
```

It hangs on the last line (`b155d168`) and after I press ctrl+c I can see black screen with mouse cursor.

Comment: Is there a reason that code plays 10 seconds of the video in an endless loop?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony That's for testing, because in production environment there will be endless loop of one video and it will be interrupted by playbacks of another videos. So I want to test if code is capable of video interruptions.

Also I found iteresting thing that when I use tkinter instead of wxpython (from your answer from other question) it works for longer time without freeze than wxpython.

Comment: try giving `--verbose=2` to `vlc_options` and post the logs here

Comment: @mfkl I edited post

Comment: why don't you use wx.media.MediaCtrl?

Comment: @LeonardoScotti you mean instead of `python-vlc`?

Comment: yes, it can be not related to your answer, it was just in general, and not a crithic, only an innocent question

Comment: @LeonardoScotti thank you, I didn't know about that. I will try it if I can't make this code work